# How do I make my electron apps communicate locally between different machines

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, electron

I have two electron apps. One is a server on machine1 and another is a client on machine2.
When I start the server from the electron app on machine1, I want machine2 (the client) to be able to be able to receive and send data to machine1 (the server).

I tried using http://localhost approach which works for the app during development but doesn't work for the packaged app which is installed on the machine.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you package an Electron app, it is no longer running on **localhost**, it runs on the IP address of the machine on which it is installed.

To establish communication between the server and client apps, you will need to use the **IP address of the machine** on which the **server app is running**. You can use the **os module in Node.js to determine the IP address of the machine** on which the server app is running. Once you have the IP address, you can **use it to connect the client app to the server app**.

You can also use a package like ip to get the IP address of the machine.

```
const ip = require('ip');
console.log(ip.address());
```

Hope this helps.